# how to convert List<Object[]> into List<MyClass>

Tags: list, object, casting

How do i perform casting without @SuppressWarnings("unchecked").

Comment: What's actually in the List? The signature suggests that there are Arrays of Objects, but you would like to get the Objects "flattened". Have I understood that correctly?

Comment: yes, List<Object[]> containing list of row information that i have to convert in List of  entity or bean class

Comment: Then you first have to iterate over the list, convert the rowinfos to your entity and collect the result in another list. You cannot simply cast that...